# Changes between C++ standard working drafts?

Tags: c++, c++11

N3337 is a working draft of the C++ standard that was published on 2012-01-16:

> [**N3337 (pdf)**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

It has only [minor editorial changes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3338.html) over the official C++11 standard.

N3337 was revised to N3376 on 2012-02-28:

> [**N3376 (pdf)**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf)

N3376 was revised to N3485 on 2012-11-02:

> [**N3485 (pdf)**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf)

I am interested to know the differences between N3337 and N3485?  (or equivilantely the differences between N3337 and N3376 and differences between N3376 and N3485)

One way to do this is to try and analyze the git log of:

> https://github.com/cplusplus/draft

Another way would be to dump the PDFs to text and run `diff` on them.

Is there a better way to follow the changes?  Is there a curated list of changes kept somewhere?  Perhaps at a standard location or in a standard format?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read the [C++ Editor's Report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3486.html).

Answer (score 7):

Each working draft `N<i>.pdf` appears to have a *C++ Editors Report* associated with it named `N<i+1>.html` that lists changes.

So the editors report for N3376 is called N3377 and is at:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3377.html

And the editors report for N3485 is called N3486 and is at:

[http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3377.html](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3486.html)

There is an index of all these documents at:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/

Comment: Can you please tell me:

What is N? And what the numbers stand for? Does a greater number means the latest document?

Comment: @SAM: It is just a naming scheme.  The commitee produces documents numbered N1, N2, ... in chronological order.  Among them are a few working drafts, and each is immediately followed by editors reports.

Comment: Thanks! Currently there are n3337, n3376, n3485, n3690 & n3691. Last one is latest but still isocpp.org has link of n3337 as current draft... Which should I refer? and how can I know if there are any defects in it? Please help me. I am confused with so many releases!

Comment: @SAM: It is generally understood that N3485 is the latest draft that can be considered C++11.  The following N3691 is considered pre-C++14, and has many new features not in C++11 official.

Answer (score 6):

Each revision of the draft standard reflects changes approved at the most recent standards committee meeting. The official list of changes is, thus, the list of motions approved at the meeting. If you don't have access to those, the editor's report is an unofficial summary of what changed.