# are the C++11 mutex implemented in user-space ?

Tags: c++, c++11, kernel, mutex

I am interested in knowing if the standard mentions anything about implementation of mutex in C++11, in user-space vs kernel space.

It could be that implementation is left completely platform specific.

Any helpful pointer/document that mentions about implementation will be great.

Comment: The Standard's not poisonous - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184203/changes-between-c-standard-working-drafts ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The C++ standard has no notion of "user-space", "kernel space" or anything of the kind. Exactly *how* `std::mutex` is implemented is up to your standard library implementation; the standard only defines *apparent behavior*.