# Interaction between decltype and class member name shadowing an external name

Tags: c++, gcc, scope, language-lawyer, decltype

This code

```
int clash;

struct Foo {
  decltype(clash) clash;
};
```

compiles silently on clang, but fails to compile on gcc giving the errors

> error: declaration of 'int Foo::clash' [-fpermissive]
>
> error: changes meaning of 'clash' from 'int clash' [-fpermissive]

It seems that 2 ingredients are required for the error to arise:

1. The shadowing must be done by a class member (no problem if it's a function's local scope).
2. decltype([shadowed name]) must be used in the shadowing scope before the declaration of [shadowing name].

My question is twofold:

1. Is gcc justified in rejecting this code?
2. Where does it say so in the standard?

Comment: What about: `int chash[sizeof(clash)];` ?
What does different compiler say? I guess it is not to do with C++11 complaint compilers, but how they behave in such cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`gcc` is correct the program is ill-formed, although this particular violation does not require a diagnostic so `clang` does not have to provide one.

If we look at the C++11 standard(*The closest draft would be [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)*) section `3.3.7` *Class scope* it says:

> A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its
>   context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No
>   diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

and the next rule says:

> If reordering member declarations in a class yields an alternate valid
>   program under (1) and (2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic is
>   required.

It makes sense we would want to prevent situations where reordering the declarations in a class give a different program. It is curious whether [these two rules are redundant or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26761385/1708801).

The section also provides the following example:

```
enum { i = 1 };

class X {
  char v[i]; // error: i refers to ::i
             // but when reevaluated is X::i
  int f() { return sizeof(c); } // OK: X::c
  char c;
  enum { i = 2 };
};
```

and if we try this example with `gcc` (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97971da06b99038c)*), we get an almost identical error to one your code produces:

```
 error: declaration of 'i' [-fpermissive]
 enum { i = 2 };
          ^

 error: changes meaning of 'i' from '<anonymous enum> i' [-fpermissive]
 enum { i = 1 };
```

Comment: You cited a _draft_, which means little. I'm showing you how to cite the actual standard, which is authoritative.

Comment: The drafts "meaning little" is not .. *entirely* true. Their full designation is "Standard **Working** Draft", and as such they are quite a bit more than 'just a draft'. Looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184203/changes-between-c-standard-working-drafts), it is clear they get refined gradually.