# Is rule 3 in section 3.3.7/1 from N3936 redundant?

Tags: c++, scope, language-lawyer, c++14

I recently [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26681873/1708801) dealing with a violation of [draft C++14 standard: N4140](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf) section `3.3.7` *Class scope* paragraph `1` rule `2` which says:

> A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its
>   context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No
>   diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

at the time rule `3` also seemed relevant and it says:

> If reordering member declarations in a class yields an alternate valid
>   program under (1) and (2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic is
>   required.

My initial reaction is that rule `3` seems redundant and is really just a clarification of rule `2` and does not cover any cases not already covered. A reordering that results in a alternate valid program would also have to violate rule `2`.

So is rule `3` redundant or is there some edge cases that requires both rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Defect Report 1875: Reordering declarations in class scope](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1875) rule `3` is redundant and the proposed solution is to remove rule `3`, it says:

> The need for rule #3 is not clear; it would seem that any
>   otherwise-valid reordering would have to violate rule #2 in order to
>   yield a different interpretation. Taken literally, rule #3 would also
>   apply to simply reordering nonstatic data members with no name
>   dependencies at all. Can it be simply removed?

and the proposed solution is:

> Delete the third item of 3.3.7 [basic.scope.class] paragraph 1 and
>   renumber the succeeding items

Although this defect report seems to confirm my initial suspicious I am left with a nagging feeling that perhaps rule `3` is bit broader after all. Section `3.3.7` includes the following example:

```
enum { i = 1 };

class X {
  char v[i]; // error: i refers to ::i
             // but when reevaluated is X::i
  int f() { return sizeof(c); } // OK: X::c
  char c;
  enum { i = 2 };
};
```

which violates both rule `2` and `3` but a small tweak:

```
enum { i = 1 };

class X {
  enum { i = 2 };
  char v[i];  // no longer refers to ::i 
              // but reordering can cause it to refer to ::i again

  int f() { return sizeof(c); } // OK: X::c
  char c;
};
```

seems to no longer violate rule `2` but sure seems to violate rule `3`. I would consider this code example to be troublesome since a reordering of the members could easily cause the code to be back in violation of rule 2 but no diagnostic is required to indicate this which makes this code rather fragile.

**Update**

As far as I understand rule `3` does not apply to this example mentioned by Casey in the comment:

```
class X { int a; int b; };
```

because even though there is more than one valid ordering this case does not fall under both rule `1` and `2` which rule `3` requires:

> alternate valid program under (1) and (2)

Comment: I disagree with the assertion that the last code example is undesirable. It may not the best style, but writing programs-in-the-large requires that local code be insulated to some degree against changes to the rest of the program. Requiring this class to declare `v` as `char v[X::i];` to be well-formed seems burdensome. Poor style or not, I certainly don't agree that the program should have undefined behavior ("ill-formed, NDR").

Comment: @Casey Do you agree the first case is undesirable?

Comment: I agree with this answer.

Comment: I agree that the first example is undesirable since name `i` is used before a declaration of the name `i` in the same scope. It's unfortunate that the resulting program has UB, given that the semantics are defined when the scopes in question are [namespace scopes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91dcfdfe6406c05f) or [nested block scopes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f63a5fbba5bf2cb). I wouldn't object to making a program ill-formed that refers to different entities by the same name in a single scope. References to `i` in the *second* example refer to a single entity in each scope.

Comment: @Casey note, I changed my wording to troublesome which I think may be easier to agree with. Perhaps fragile is a better word, I think it is hard to argue given rule 2 that the second example is not fragile.

Comment: I will agree with fragile - but I find it unsettling that it has UB. Interpreting rule 3 directly, it seems that even `class X { int a; int b; }; int main() {}` has undefined behavior. That's definitely a problem. If the rule isn't to be removed, I think some wording changes are in order.

Comment: @Casey I don't think it makes the case ill-formed because rule 3 specifies that *alternate valid program under (1) and (2),* which as far as I understand only applies if both `1` and `2` apply.

Comment: The "reordering rule", if I'm reading D&E correctly, dates to the time when implicit int was still a thing.  In that world, given `typedef int P(); typedef int Q(); class X { static P(Q); static Q(P); };`, reordering will really yield "an alternate valid program", and do so without running afoul of the "reconsideration rule" (i.e. #2).

Comment: @T.C. can you give me the page(s) from D&E?

Comment: §6.3.1.3, pages 141-143 in my copy