# Is there any reason for §3.3.7/1.2 to be considered an error?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This code was obtained from the example in §3.3.7/1.5:

```
enum { i = 1 };
class X {
    char v[i]; // error: i refers to ::i
    // but when reevaluated is X::i
    enum { i = 2 };
};
```

[GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6c21f3287e78b22) emits an error because of §3.3.7/1.2

However, if we apply §3.4.1/7, the lookup for the name `i` in the declaration `char v[i];` will find `enum{ i = 1 };` in global scope. What's the problem with the redeclaration `enum{ i = 2 };`?

Comment: Related to [Is rule 3 in section 3.3.7/1 from N3936 redundant?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26761385/1708801)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in member function scope (and other class scopes) the class version of the enum shadows the global value.

If it wasn't an error, the compiler would have to pick one of two surprising behaviors:

1) Use the class enum's value always, which means it would have to fully parse the class to determine if a valid size is available.

2) Have the value of `i` within class members *be completely different* from the *actual* length of the class member array declared, notionally, to be the same length.

Comment: I understand this. But I don't see a reason for an error.

Comment: @Ayrosa what should `sizeof X{}.v` yield?

Comment: Your number (2) justifies it. Thanks.