# Use of 'auto func(int)' before deduction of 'auto' in C++14

Tags: c++, function, gcc, c++14, auto

I have compiled following program in GCC using `C++14`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto func(int i);

int main() 
{
    auto ret = func(5);
    return 0;
}

auto func(int i) 
{
  if (i == 1)
    return i;              
  else
    return func(i-1) + i;  
}
```

But, I get the following error.

> ```
> In function 'int main()': 8:16: error: use of 'auto func(int)' before
> deduction of 'auto'
>  auto ret = func(5);
> ```

So, what am I missing here?

Comment: Remember that C++ is designed for one-pass compilers (and many for it still are). The deduction for `ret` depends on `func`, but that cannot be available yet when preforming a single pass translation.

Comment: What return type do you think should be given to `func` and why?

Comment: @n.m.  return type int because func() return's sum of 1 to n numbers.

Comment: Only now have I realized that the function in your question is identical to the one in the example in the standard... Is that a coincidence? Because if it isn't, then you've just missed the 2nd and 3rd lines of the example. (Yes, I do realize this is a pretty common recursion scheme. Just making sure.)

Comment: Oops my mistake, please ignore.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm not sure it's possible for fully-compliant compilers to be single-pass, per the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29662526/1858225). In any case, it certainly seems quite difficult. But you're absolutely right that much of C++ is designed *as if* this were the desired approach.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is [[dcl.spec.auto/11]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#11):

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed
>   to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed.
>   Once a non-discarded return statement has been seen in a function,
>   however, the return type deduced from that statement can be used in
>   the rest of the function, including in other return statements.
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> auto n = n;                     // error, n's type is unknown
> auto f();
> void g() { &f; }                // error, f's return type is unknown
> auto sum(int i) {
>   if (i == 1)
>     return i;                   // sum's return type is int
>   else
>     return sum(i-1)+i;          // OK, sum's return type has been deduced
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

To translate this into English: the compiler needs to know the return type before you can use the function. In case of `auto` used like this, this is typically achieved by moving the definition before the point of use. If you don't actually need to use return type deduction, you can keep the definition after the use if you provide a signature, including the return type, in the declaration.

Comment: Gotta love them standard quotes.

Comment: Straight to the point, great answer! I think it's also worth mentioning that even if in this case it looks like the compiler should be able to magically infer the return type even if `f` is defined after `main`, the problem really appears when the definition of `f` is in a separate translation unit: in that case, it's way too hard for the compiler to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 35):

Clang has a much better error message for that one:

```
main.cpp:8:16: error: function 'func' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined
    auto ret = func(5);
               ^
```

I guess that's self-explanatory.

Comment: And as a side note, I suppose that's where the H-M inference comes in to actually be able to skip that, get the definition, and then check the thing properly.

Comment: Gotta love them clang quotes.

Answer (score 6):

When `auto` is used as the return type in a function declaration that does not use the trailing return type syntax, the keyword `auto` indicates that the return type will be deduced from the operand of its return statement. That means the deduction can't be performed until the definition of the function `func()`, but before that it has been used in `main()`.

You could move the definition before `main()`, or use trailing return type syntax to specify the return type on the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, there is really no reason that you could not just move the implementation of the function before `main()`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;  // you should avoid this, too

auto func(int i)
{
  if (i == 1)
    return i;
  else
    return func(i-1) + i;
}

int main()
{
    auto ret = func(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise you just can't use the auto keyword. In particular, you can't use auto in a recursive function which does not return anything. You have to use `void`. And that applies to lambda functions. For example:

```
int main()
{
    auto func = [](int i)
    {
        // ... do something with `i` ...
        if(i > 0)
        {
            func(i - 1);   // <-- same error here
        }
    }

    auto ret(func(5));
    return 0;
}
```

The call `func(i - 1)` has a problem. To fix it you have to replace the `auto` by the actual type:

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::function<void(int)> func_t;
    func_t func = [](int i)
    {
    ...
```

If you really want a function which supports varying return types you want to use a template anyway, not `auto`. This is really only to help you with less typing, not so much as a way to allow "any type".