# Variadic Macro: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type through '...'

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-macros

I am trying to write a macro for logging mechanism. I wrote a variadic macro but it does not work with `std::string`. The code looks like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>


#define LOG_NOTE(m, ...) printf(m, ##__VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    std::string foo = "random string";
    int bar = 5;
    LOG_NOTE("%s %d %s", "Hello World", bar, foo);

    return 0;
}
```

If I would call the macro like following, I would not get any error.

```
LOG_NOTE("%s %d %s", "Hello World", bar, "random string");
```

**Compiler Output:**

> In function 'int main()': 5:49: error: cannot pass objects of
>   non-trivially-copyable type 'std::string {aka class
>   std::basic_string}' through '...' 11:5: note: in expansion of
>   macro 'LOG_NOTE'

Comment: btw if you use gcc its the `-E` flag to get the output after the preprocessor, helps a lot when writing macros.

Comment: Do you need format, or is it just space separated values ?

Comment: I actually need just space separated values, and currently I am trying to implement it based on the answer but I'm getting a linker error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wrote a variadic macro

Don't. Use a variadic template function.

The actual problem you have is that you're trying to pass a C++ object (`std::string`) through a C API (`printf`). This is not possible.

You'd need some mechanism for conversion, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

template<class T>
decltype(auto) convert_for_log_note(T const& x)
{
    return x;
}

decltype(auto) convert_for_log_note(std::string const& x)
{
    return x.c_str();
}


template<class...Args> 
void LOG_NOTE(const char* format, Args&&...args)
{
    printf(format, convert_for_log_note(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    std::string foo = "random string";
    int bar = 5;
    LOG_NOTE("%s %d %s\n", "Hello World", bar, foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
Hello World 5 random string
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/beb3431114833860

Update:

For C++11 you'll need to spell out the return types by hand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

template<class T>
T const& convert_for_log_note(T const& x)
{
    return x;
}

const char* convert_for_log_note(std::string const& x)
{
    return x.c_str();
}


template<class...Args> 
void LOG_NOTE(const char* format, Args&&...args)
{
    printf(format, convert_for_log_note(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    std::string foo = "random string";
    int bar = 5;
    LOG_NOTE("%s %d %s\n", "Hello World", bar, foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In all fairness, logging macro's are a well-known exemption from the "no macro's" rule, for three reasons: `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and the ability to turn them into do-nothing statements in release builds. You can't eliminate side effects from function call arguments.

Comment: @MSalters as long as the c++ committee behave themselves, we'll soon have std::source_location, which along with `if constexpr`, will eliminate the need for macros altogether. Note that the argument side-effects are not an issue as long as you pass the arguments by universal reference. Obviously passing LOG("%s%", mything.to_string().c_str()); does invoke side-effects and should obviously be avoided. Better to provide an ADL overload for `convert_for_log_note(MyThing const&)` type.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, but it does not seem to work in C++11 at least not with GNU GCC v7.1.1 using `g++ -std=c++11`. It does work however in C++14. Anyone know how to modify this to make it work in C++11?

Comment: @Oliver I've added an update which will compile for c++11. https://godbolt.org/z/M5GmyD

Comment: This is super cool. One thing I ran into was that the ability to use `decltype(auto)` as the return type of the `std::string` specialization of the `convert_for_log_note` template depends on how it is first used in the code. (Something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43514762/430067.) I just changed it to `const char*` because I did not see any reason for the generic return type.

Answer (score 6):

The issue here is not the variadic macro, but the call to `printf`. Have a look at the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf): the format specifier `"%s"` corresponds to `char*`, not `std::string`. `printf` can only handle primitive builtin types. You can change you invocation to

```
LOG_NOTE("%s %d %s", "Hello World", bar, foo.c_str());
```

to fix this.

Comment: Alternatively, use Boost Format. It does support `std::string` and many other user-defined types.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pass object to `printf`, so you have currently to use

```
LOG_NOTE("%s %d %s", "Hello World", bar, foo.c_str());
```

If you don't need formatting, and just write every argument separated with space, you might simply use variadic template instead of MACRO:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void LOG_NOTE(const Ts&...args)
{
    const char* sep = "";
    (((std::cout << sep << args), sep = " "), ...); // C++17 folding expression
    // C++11/C++14 version are more verbose:
    // int dummy[] = {0, ((std::cout << sep << args), (sep = " "), 0)...};
    // static_cast<void>(dummy); // avoid warning for unused variable
}

int main()
{
    std::string foo = "random string";
    int bar = 5;
    LOG_NOTE("Hello World", bar, foo);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01b4f532cf98da7a)

Comment: Thanks for your input @Jarod42 but I already found similar answer for C++17. However, I am looking for C++11 example with header and source files separated.

Comment: `template` are not good candidate to split between header and cpp files.

Comment: C++11 version added.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get @richardhodges nice solution to work in any of the C++11 compilers I tried. However, the following works with `gcc -std=c++11`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

template<class T>
T convert_for_log_note(T const& x)
{
    return x;
}

inline const char* convert_for_log_note(std::string const& x)
{
    return x.c_str();
}


template<class...Args> 
void LOG_NOTE(const char* format, Args&&...args)
{
    printf(format, convert_for_log_note(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    std::string foo = "random string";
    int bar = 5;
    LOG_NOTE("%s %d %s\n", "Hello World", bar, foo);

    return 0;
}
```

The `inline` keyword is necessary with the above solution for the Arduino C++ compiler, whereas other g++ compilers do not require it (the ones I have tried, anyways). Without this keyword, the Arduino code compiles, but the linker complains about multiple definitions.