# Recursive lambda fails to compile if return type is not specified

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda, c++14

Below code fails to compile (in gcc9.2):

```
#include<iostream>

int main () {
    auto func = [](auto _func, int n) {
        std::cout << n << '\n';
        if (n > 1) {
            _func(_func, n - 1);
        }
    };
    func(func, 3);
}
```

Unless I specify the return type as below:

```
#include<iostream>

int main () {
    auto func = [](auto _func, int n)->void {
        std::cout << n << '\n';
        if (n > 1) {
            _func(_func, n - 1);
        }
    };
    func(func, 3);
}
```

Why do we need to explicitly specify the return type here?

**Edit-1:** The compilation error is:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'main()::<lambda(auto:1, int)> [with auto:1 = main()::<lambda(auto:1, int)>]':

<source>:10:17:   required from here

<source>:7:18: error: use of 'main()::<lambda(auto:1, int)> [with auto:1 = main()::<lambda(auto:1, int)>]' before deduction of 'auto'

    7 |             _func(_func, n - 1);

      |             ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

ASM generation compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Probably because the compiler can't recursively infer a type from the function as the signature depends on itself. It's like a circular dependency so it would resolve to undefined behavior.

Declaring the type would break that circular loop of discovering the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to compile this, I get the following message:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'main()::<lambda(auto:1, int)> [with auto:1 = main()::<lambda(auto:1, int)>]':
main.cpp:10:17:   required from here
main.cpp:7:18: error: use of 'main()::<lambda(auto:1, int)> [with auto:1 = main()::<lambda(auto:1, int)>]' before deduction of 'auto'
    7 |             _func(_func, n - 1);
      |             ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The key is

> error: use of 'lambda' before deduction of 'auto'

A simpler example would be something like

```cpp
#include<iostream>

auto f(int x) {
    std::cout << x << " ";
    if (x > 0)
        f(x - 1);
}

int main() {
    f(3);   
}
```

which gives much the same error.

In essence, the compiler can't know until its finished processing the function what return type it needs to be, but it can't finish processing the function until it works out what `f` is returning. There's a circular dependency here, so the compiler gives an error.

See also [Use of 'auto func(int)' before deduction of 'auto' in C++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514665/use-of-auto-funcint-before-deduction-of-auto-in-c14).