# name lookup for typedef is buggy in GNU compiler?

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, language-lawyer, name-lookup

The following  code

```
#include <iostream>

typedef double A; // a global typedef

template <class Z> struct B // a template class...
{
    A i{22.2}; // global typedef is in scope
    typedef int A; // now  a local typedef with the same name is introduced
    A b{24};  // now the local typedef is in scope
    Z c{36}; // a simple member of the template type
};

template <class Z> struct C : B<Z> // a template struct inheriting B
{
    A a;  // global typedef is in scope because we are in a template struct
    C(  ) : a(2.2){  }
};

int main(  )
{
    C<int> c;
    std::cout << "c's members: "
           << c.a << ' '
           << c.i << ' '
           << c.b << ' '
           << c.c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "their sizeof: "
           << sizeof(c.a) << ' ' 
           << sizeof(c.i) << ' '
           << sizeof(c.b) << ' '
           << sizeof(c.c) <<  std::endl;
}
```

is NOT compiled by `GNU-g++ 4.9.2` while it is by `clang 3.5.0` and behaves as I tried to explain in the embedded comments and as it can be seen by the output produced. Is this a bug in the GNU compiler?
The diagnostic says that the line `typedef int A;` in the scope of the
`struct B`

> error: changes meaning of ‘A’ from ‘typedef double A’

Note that when the hierarchy is not made of `template` (and of course the `Z c{36};` declaration is removed) the lookup performed by `clang` in the scope of `C` (correctly, as I suppose) finds the `typedef` in the scope of `B` and considers the member `a` to be of
type `int`; then it issues a warning about the narrowing of the initializing `double` constant `2.2`...

Comment: Similar to [Interaction between decltype and class member name shadowing an external name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26681873/1708801)

Comment: Can you format and shorten that code appropriately?

Comment: What's with the bizarre indentation?

Answer (score 9):

From the c++ standard draft (N4140)

§3.3.7 [basic.scope.class]

> 2) A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

`A i{22.2}` initially refers to the global `::A`. But after `B::A` is declared, when re-evaluated in the completed scope of `B`, it would refer to `B::A`. This violates the rule above.

To fix it, use the fully qualified name: `::A i{22.2}`. `::A` always refers to the global `A` even after `B::A` is declared, so it doesn't violate the rule.

This is not a bug in g++; it's just an ill-formed program. The compiler is not required not give you a diagnostic for the violation of the rule, but it's not required to accept it either.